# Use multiple radio buttons to filter table data

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have some data in a table:

```
<table>
<tr>
 <th>Month</th>
 <th>Savings</th>
 <th>Rate</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>January</td>
 <td>$100</td>
 <td>5%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>March</td>
 <td>$200</td>
 <td>4%</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to use radio buttons with the following logic:

1. All - January - March
2. All - $100 - $200
3. All - >4% - >5%

How could I use JavaScript to search the table data, and show rows based on the outputs of *multiple* radio buttons and not just one?

Comment: Can you please explain a little more what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I wanted to keep it as simple as possible. All I want to do is have several radio buttons. The selections of these radio buttons would filter out rows of data that didn't fit the logic for those buttons. So a range, or a string of text for example. How do you 'search' the table data for the rows that contain the right content, and filter them based on the radio buttons selected?

Comment: Ok, now I think I understood. You want radioboxes to filter you table. right?

Comment: Yes, can you help please? :)

Comment: is your table data dynamic?

Comment: not the data being filtered, but I will have a column that shows .js calculation outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Did an oopsie where i filtered what was supposed to be shown. Code is updated below.

I did a test page with one set of radio buttons, but the same logic will work for a new set of radio buttons whose "name" attribute is the filter you want to apply.

See the code below in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/3mdc7ppb/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="TblRates">
<tr class="headerRow">
 <th>Month</th>
 <th>Savings</th>
 <th>Rate</th>
</tr>
<tr class="dataRow">
 <td>January</td>
 <td>$100</td>
 <td>5%</td>
</tr>
<tr class="dataRow">
 <td>March</td>
 <td>$200</td>
 <td>4%</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="radio" name="Month"  value="All" checked="checked" />All<br/>
<input type="radio" name="Month"  value="January"/>January<br/>
<input type="radio" name="Month"  value="March"/>March<br/>

<script>
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
    var filter = this.value;
    if (filter == "All")
        $("tr.dataRow").css( "visibility", "visible" );
    else $("tr.dataRow").css( "visibility", "collapse" );
    var matchFound = false;
    $("tr.dataRow").find("td").each(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      if (!matchFound){
          if ($this.html() == filter){
            matchFound = true;
            $this.parent().css( "visibility", "visible" );
          }
      }
    });
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope to have understand right, but is similar to this question:

[radio-button-filter-using-jquery-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594652/radio-button-filter-using-jquery-javascript)

I try to show a scratch in a fiddler similar to your needs: [jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/z3dqm0qp/1/)

```
$('tr').each(function() {
        ...
});
```

You have to implement the range controls.

#### The answer of IlGala with html5 is better

Usually is much easier if you use a framework or a library to handle this with bindings (like angularjs or knockoutjs). Give it a try!

Regards

Edit: to answer to your comment

You have to work in the conditions, try to split in simpler check. Really, bindings will help you. :)

```
if (price > val2 && price < val3 || ...){
    $(this).show();
} else {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Comment: can you show me how I would have radio options that were say: up to 60, up to 70, up to 90. And then hide rows based on numerical cell contents in a certain column?

Comment: give a look to [this](http://ryanrahlf.com/filtering-table-data-with-knockout-js/) and its relative [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/rrahlf/EZUEF/6/). Looks harder but it isn't so much, and you will recover the time later when your project get bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a mix of HTML5 data tags and jquery.

The radio buttons should have a `data-first-value` and `data-second-value` in order to recover the range. the worst part is to check the rows since there is some "complex" text and not simply the value you're looking for. But there are a lot of [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074687/filtering-table-rows-using-jquery) to achive your goal.

here is an example of how your code can look like.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".radio").click(function() {        
        // hide all table rows

        // Get the rest of checked radios
        var checkedRadios = $('.radio:checked');

        // Iterate the checked radios
        $.each(checkedRadios, function(idx, element){
            // Table rows filter:
            // 1) iterate the rows
            // 2) if the table respects the filter => show
        });
    });
});
```

This is one of the simplest way to hide/show the results you need.